# how to delete a dynamically allocated 2d array?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 int **arr;
 arr=new int*[3];
 arr[0]=new int [4];
 arr[1]=new int [4];
 arr[2]=new int [5];
 arr[2][0]=20;
 cout << arr[2][0] << endl;
 delete []arr;
 cout << arr[2][0];
}
```

I used a double pointer to create a 2d array in heap.The output before and after "delete []arr" is same. what is the mistake here and how does "delete" works in the background?

Comment: There is no mistake here: `delete` doesn't (necessarily) implies _overwriting_ and/or _deallocating_. Nonetheless using memory after delete is _Undefined Behaviour,_ so anything can happen. Note if you used four `new`, you have to use four `delete` otherwise you will leak memory.

Comment: You are making two mistakes, and what's mysterious about how `delete` works?

Comment: It is not a 2D array. It is an 1D array of pointers. A 2D array is a fully contiguous zone in the memory.

Comment: This should all be done with just [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) IMHO. Ditch that stupid and error prone manual memory management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deleting array of pointers, not the actual 1D arrays.

```
    //Free sub-array's first
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        delete[] arr[i];   
    }
    //Free the array of pointers
    delete[] arr;
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You should preferably avoid the problem by using smart pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]> arr = std::make_unique<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]>(3);
    arr[0] = std::make_unique<int[]>(4);
    arr[1] = std::make_unique<int[]>(4);
    arr[2] = std::make_unique<int[]>(4);
    arr[2][0] = 20;
    std::cout << arr[2][0] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: One should probably learn about `std::vector` before pointers (however smart).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. That too :-)